# RegEx in PHP to return array

Tags: php, regex

I'm converting some shortcode information from an old CMS I'm using.  In some article body text, I need to get the ID from some pre-existing callouts

```
{image id="27411" shape="landscape" align="right"}
```

There can be multiple callouts like this within one body of text.  Is there a way to have this information returned as an array of IDs?  The only important information is the ID, the rest is irrelevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's always in that format, use [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/preg_match_all), like this:

```
preg_match_all( '#\{image id="(\d+)"[^\}]+\}#', $input, $matches);
```

Your array of IDs will be in `$matches[1]`.

So, for your example input, this [outputs](http://viper-7.com/totFcP):

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "27411"
}
```

Comment: I think the `{` must/should be escaped, because `{…}` delimits repetition specifiers. It would only not be an error because nothing precedes it here. But it makes modifications harder.

Comment: @PointedEars - [It still works](http://viper-7.com/C2aXDK) if something precedes it. While it's good practice and I will update my answer, I believe it works because `{` is not followed by a number.

Answer (score 1):

The following pattern should do the job:

```
/image id\="(\d+)"/
```

Required id is in group 1.

[Demo](http://regexr.com?31i9g)